# Core data to-many relationship NSOrderedSet containment check fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have a core data model setup like this:

`Parent <-->> Child`. This `parent.children` relationship is ordered.

1. I create a new `Parent` object (with no `Child` object) and upload it to a web server.
2. While the upload is going on in the background, I create a new `Child` object with `child.parent` set to the parent object in step 1. Then *I set the child object as a property in a view controller.*
3. The upload of Step 1 finishes and I call `save` on the managedObjectContext.
4. From the view controller, I call `save` on the managedObjectContext again.
5. Next, when I do `[self.child.parent.children containsObject:self.child]` in the view controller, I get `false`.

In the view controller, I checked the `objectID` of both `self.child` and `[(Child *)self.child.parent.children objectAtIndex:0]` and they are both the same.

There is only one `NSManagedObjectContext` being used here.

So I am not sure what is causing the NSOrderedSet containment set to return false, or even what additional information should I log to debug this problem.

**Edit 1: Providing some code**

The save is done through `RestKit`'s `NSManagedObjectContext+RKAdditions` category.
The code to save is in `saveToPersistentStore` with link here:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/CoreData/NSManagedObjectContext%2BRKAdditions.m#L39
This method internally calls `performBlockAndWait` so calling this from any thread is OK.

The upload is done through `RestKit` too, and in the completion handler, one property of the `parent` object is updated and then `[parent.managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore]` is called.

The viewController has a property called `child`. When initializing the view controller, the property is passed to the init method and then set

```
- (id) initWithChild:(Child *)child
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.child = child;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Later on a button tap, the `saveToPersistentStore` is called on the managedObjectContext again.
Once that is done, I try `[self.child.parent.children containsObject:self.child]`

Comment: You cannot use/access the same managed context or managed object in two different threads. you cannot call save on a single managed object, only on the entire context (and only in the thread/queue the context is created in or using). please provide the BG code of the "upload" and the code in the view controller accessing the context.

Comment: @DanShelly: Provided additional code info. You are correct that the save is called on the managedObjectContext, it was bad framing of question on my part.

Comment: When you set the relationship, does your check work immediately? Are you POSTing the parent?

Comment: @Wain: Yes, the check does work immediately, I am `POST`ing the `parent`

Comment: This might be obvious, but are the `parent` and `children` relationships configured as inverse relationships in the Core Data model?

Comment: @TomHarrington: Yes the 'parent' and 'children' relationships are indeed correctly configured as inverse